# MongoDB: find if ID exist in array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I was wondering, is there a way in MongoDB to get all the documents from one collection excluding those that exists in another, without using aggregation.

Let me explain myself more;

I have a collection of "Users", and another collection where there is an array of objects.
Something like this:

**User**

```
  }
    "_id": "61e6bbe49d7efc57f895ab50",
    "name": "User 1"
  },
  {
    "_id": "61e6b9239d7efc57f895ab02",
    "name": "User 2"
  },
  {
    "_id": "61cae6176d0d9a36efd8f190",
    "name": "User 3"
  },
  {
    "_id": "61cade886d0d9a36efd8f11a",
    "name": "User 4"
  },
```

The other collection looks like this:

```
{
    users: [
        {
           user: {
              "_id": "61e6b9239d7efc57f895ab02",
              "name": "User 2",
           },
           ...

        },
        {
           user: {
              "_id": "61cae6176d0d9a36efd8f190",
              "name": "User 3",
           },
           ...
        },
    ],
},
```

I would like to get all the users in "array 1" excluding those in "array 2".
So the result should be:

```
    [
        {
           "_id": "61e6b9239d7efc57f895ab02",
           "name": "User 1"
        },
        {
           "_id": "61cae6176d0d9a36efd8f190",
           "name": "User 4"
        },
    ],
```

So, is there a way to do that without the need to do aggregation.

Comment: You can fire two queries if you don't want aggregation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking for a solution, if you want to add new element to an array of objects, where you, somehow, forgot to initialize the **_id** field, remember you have to, because mongo adds that field automatically (to use it for filtering/indexation).

All you have to do, is to write something like this;

```
const data = Data.create({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId.createFromHexString(uid),
    users: [{ user: userId, initiator: true, _id: userId}],
})
```

and for the searching, you write what you always write;

```
const found = await User.find({ _id: { $nin: data.users } });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `$and` like this:

```
const found = await User.find({
    $and: [
      { _id: { $in: array1 } },
      { _id: { $nin: array2 } }
    ]
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ... your answer is kinda what I already wrote, but when I used to add a new element to the array I didn't initialize the "_id" so mongo gives a default _id to each new element ... all I had to do is modify that custom behavior and initialize the _id with the user's _id.